# testmethod that publishes platform events - GACK 255731747

Tags: unit-test, platform-event

Use case:

- Testmethod that invokes a service with more than 200 Sobjects
- Service does work on each Sobject and as a side effect, also publishes Platform Events
- By varying the number of Sobjects, at some point, the testmethod fails with an internal server error (gack) with error code **255731747**.  No other exception thrown or caught.

What is the cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank goodness we have premier support as within a few hours, I had the stacktrace for the Gack:

```
Internal Salesforce Error: 493985485-49401 (255731747) (255731747)

SourceClassName: data.api.event.EventConduitDataSourceConnection

SourceMethodName: upsertRows

Subject: Sandbox: Sandbox: Error during SoapOperationRunTests at
data.api.event.EventConduitDataSourceTable.publish(EventConduitDataSourceTable.java:58)

ExtendedMessage: data.api.DataSourceException: Failed to publish events

Thrown: data.api.DataSourceException: Failed to publish events

Cause0: common.exception.ApiException: Event push failed

Cause1: common.api.conduit.PlatformEventPublisher$PublishException: Error publishing 100 platform events

Cause2: common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Too many platform events enqueued for this apex test context

Cause3: common.exception.LimitExceededException: Too many platform events enqueued for this apex test context
```

So, the issue is that Salesforce is not throwing a Limits exception in this case but is instead just abruptly dying.  The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_test_events.htm) states the following:

> In addition, event allocations don’t apply to test events, which have their own publishing limit of 500 event messages in a test method.

My testmethod was generating in sequence (one transaction):

- 200 Platform events
- 3 Platform Events
- 200 Platform events
- 3 Platform events (cumulative 406)
- 100 Platform events *this is the stacktrace above;  406 + 100 > 500* **KABOOM**

So, while subscribing triggers can be presented with up to 2000 platform events, Apex (testmethod) can't generate more than 500 platform events.

My use case was using platform events as a backup mechanism for an incoming mass transaction where #sobjects could be 1...2000. I wanted to verify that CPU Limits would not be exceeded --but ran into the gack and the 500 publishable events in a testmethod. Volume testing of this nature can't be done in testmethods and instead requires execute anonymous, POSTMAN, or some other external client.

> UPDATE - This is now a [Known
>   Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmbDQAS)
>   - Be sure to mark this as "affects me" if appropriate
>
> UPDATE - Fixed in [Spring 19 Patch 4.0](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmbDQAS)